# Use a while loop to count down numbers and finding the square root

Tags: java

How do I use a `while` loop to count down the input number with the square root?

For example, if I were to run the code and put the first number as 8 it would give me the square root of 8..7..6.. and so on.

Below is my code so far; right now, I only get the square root of the first number:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start;
    int i;
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    start = scnr.nextInt();
    if (start < 0) {
        System.out.print("Error, enter a positive integer");
    } else {
        for(i = start; i != 0; i--); {
            double sqrt = Math.sqrt(start);
            start--;
            System.out.printf("%,4f", sqrt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to convert the `for` loop to a `while` loop?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes

Comment: What is your issue with using a [while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop?

Comment: typo: invalid `;` after for loop makes the loop body execute only one time `for(i = start; i != 0; i--);`

Comment: `while (start > 0) { System.out.printf("%4f%n", Math.sqrt(start--)); }`

Comment: Holy indentation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow coding123 ! I flagged your question as "caused by a typo and therefore unlikely to be helpful to other users". If other people agree with my personal assessment your question might end up being deleted. However, this should not discourage you from asking questions! We look forward to your contribution on StackOverflow ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int start = scnr.nextInt();
        if (start < 0) {
            System.out.print("Error, enter a positive integer");
        } else {
            while (start !=0) {
                double sqrt = Math.sqrt(start);
                System.out.printf("%d: %,4f\n", start, sqrt);
                start--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output

```java
Enter a positive integer: 36
36: 6.000000
35: 5.916080
34: 5.830952
33: 5.744563
32: 5.656854
31: 5.567764
30: 5.477226
29: 5.385165
28: 5.291503
27: 5.196152
26: 5.099020
25: 5.000000
24: 4.898979
23: 4.795832
22: 4.690416
21: 4.582576
20: 4.472136
19: 4.358899
18: 4.242641
17: 4.123106
16: 4.000000
15: 3.872983
14: 3.741657
13: 3.605551
12: 3.464102
11: 3.316625
10: 3.162278
9: 3.000000
8: 2.828427
7: 2.645751
6: 2.449490
5: 2.236068
4: 2.000000
3: 1.732051
2: 1.414214
1: 1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement as a while loop

```
int i = start;
while(i >= 0){
   //your variable i is decrementing not start, so Math.sqrt(i)

  double sqrt = Math.sqrt(i);
  System.out.println(sqrt);
  i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution for ya and i fixed the indentation as well. There was a semicolon after your if statement making it useless. I implemented a while loop as you requested which will display the number then its square root, decreasing by 1 each iteration. Let me know how this works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start;
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    start = scnr.nextInt();
    if (start < 0) {
        System.out.print("Error, enter a positive integer");
    }
    while (start > 0) {
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(start);
        System.out.println(start + " - " + sqrt);
        start--;
    }
}
```